# Querying from Snowflake in R via DBI imports � symbol

Tags: r, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbi

I try to query some data from a table in Snowflake into Rstudio.
I've set-up ODBC properly and execute the below R code:

```
Data <-dbGetQuery(snowflake, " SELECT * FROM my_table")
```

Then, I get the data into a data frame but there are some entries which show � character.
For example the German word `Groß` is imported as `Gro�` into R.
I checked the original `my_table` and the data are stored without � symbols there.
How may I fix this issue?

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue. Per `odbc` author [here](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/67#issuecomment-308228848), try `encoding="latin1"` in `dbConnect` (or whatever encoding supports German characters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying the encoding fixed the issue

```
dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "snowflake", uid="username", pwd='password',encoding = "latin1")
Data <-dbGetQuery(snowflake, " SELECT * FROM my_table")
```